# Sum values based on first occurrence of other column using excel formula and criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There have been answers previously explaining how to SUM only the first instance. E.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT( (A2:A25<>"") / COUNTIF(A2:A25,A2:A25&""),D2:D25)`

When looking to only `SUM` the values in D on the first instance of a label in A. How would you add a criteria to this formula? i.e. In C the values must equal to "yes"?

Answer (score 1):

Use COUNTIFS with a changing range to see if it is the first then use SUMIFS:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:A2,A2)=1,SUMIFS(D:D,C:C,"yes",A:A,A2),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMIFS`.

For example: `=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$25, $C$2:$C$25, "yes", $A$2:$A$25, "<>"&"")`